# Finding the value of $a$ and the value of $b$ using calculus

Tags: calculus

So this is a simple calculus problem, but since I have no way of checking my answer I would appreciate if someone could tell me the answer.

> The slope of a curve $y=x^2+ax+b$ at the point $(2,-4)$ is $-1$.  Find the value of $a$ and the value of $b$.

According to my calculations a is -1 and b -6. Is this correct?

Comment: You suggest $x^2 - x - 6.$ When $x=2,$ get $4 - 2 - 6 = 2 - 6 = -4.$ Next, derivative is $2x-1.$ at $x=2,$ derivative is $2 \cdot 2 - 1 = 3$

Comment: But you do have a way to check your answer. Once you've found $a$ and $b$, plug in these values in your equation, then verify that $(2,-4)$ verifies the equation $y=x^2+a x+b$. Then find the derivative and verify that it is equal to $-1$ when $x=2$.

Answer (score 3):

Given $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$, try this:

$$f'(2)=-1$$